# Finding extrema, non-critical points, and saddle points given a contour plot

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I'm trying to interpret the contour plot as like a mountain, where all the segregated areas are plains that are higher when it proceeds inwards. What is the significance of the numbers on x-axis and y-axis, and wouldn't the points that are most centered be maximums?

$\hskip 12 in$[image]

Comment: B,D are critical, A saddle and C is non-critical point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea is:

1. When a point is surrounded by concentric closed contour lines, it have to be a extrema, because as you cross the contour lines, the height is continuously changing, and at the center you will get the zero change.
2. When two contour lines cross their is a saddle point.
3. Neither of two stated happens, then it is non-critical point.

So here, points B, D are extrema, A is saddle point, and C is non-critical point.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution indicates that B is a minimum and D is a maximum. This doesn't really make sense to me, since B is pretty much in the middle of the graph, wouldn't the height be the greatest? So, in another word, it makes more sense that B is a maximum; whereas, D is a minimum.

Comment: Nothing can be said about the nature of extrema unless the value is stated in the contour plot.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll let my professor know.

Answer (score 2):

There are incorrect statements in the accepted answer, and there are some subtleties not mentioned.

1. Concentric closed contour lines always indicate either a local minimum or a local maximum.
2. For a well-defined function, two contour lines with different values can *never* intersect. Since contour lines indicate function values, if two different contour lines were to intersect, the function would have two different values at that point, which is impossible. So a function is undefined at a point where two different contour lines intersect.
3. If a contour line intersects itself, the point could be a saddle point, local minimum, or local maximum.  For example, $f(x,y) = x y$ has a saddle point at the origin where the $0$-contour line intersects itself, $f(x,y) = x^2 y^2$ has a local minimum at the origin where the $0$-contour line intersects itself, and $f(x,y) = -x^2 y^2$ has a local maximum at the origin where the $0$-contour line intersects itself.
4. Without the values of the contour lines, nothing can be said about a point of intersection of contour lines. It could be a point at which the function is undefined, a saddle point, or a local extrema.

To answer the question, it appears that points $B$ and $D$ are local extrema, which could be minima or maxima. The function $C$ is not a critical point. Not much can be said about the point $A$ - if the values of the contour lines that are tangent at $A$ are different, then point $A$ looks like a point where the slope becomes infinite.  On the other hand, if the values are the same, then the point $A$ could be a local minimum, local maximum, or a saddle point.

A possible function which would generate the contour plot (shown on the left below) in the question is
$$
f(x,y) = ((x-1)^2 + y^2 - 1) \left( \left(x - \frac{3}{2} \right)^2 + y^2 - \frac{9}{4} \right) , 
$$
which will have a zero set consisting of a circle of radius $1$ centered at $(1,0)$ and a circle of radius $3/2$ centered at $(3/2,0)$. Thus, the 0-contours will be tangent at $(0,0)$, where there is a critical point. In this case, there is a saddle point at $(0,0)$: there is a path convergint to $(0,0)$ consisting of points outside the circle $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ and inside the circle $(x-3/2)^2 + y^2 = 9/4$ along which $f(x,y) < 0$, and also a path along the $x$-axis converging to $(0,0)$ along which $f(x,y) > 0$.

However, the function $g(x,y) = f(x,y)^2$ will have a similar contour plot (shown to the right below) - in particular the same zero set - and still a critical point at $(0,0)$, but is everywhere positive, and so the point $(0,0)$ where the contour lines are tangent is a local minimum.

[image: Contour plot of f(x,y)] [image: Contour plot of g(x,y) = f(x,y)^2]